# DataTables with FixedColumns extension breaks jQuery trigger in table header

Tags: jquery, triggers, datatables

**How do you get jQuery triggers to work in the column header when using the FixedColumns extension for DataTables?**

I'm using DataTables with the FixedColumns extension.
I have a jQuery trigger in the table header which is not working when using FixedColumns.

When the jQuery trigger is outside the table, everything works:

http://live.datatables.net/nopiyuja/1/edit?html,js,console,output

When the jQuery trigger is put into the table (in the first column header), it no longer works.

http://live.datatables.net/gupalata/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is content of datatables is loaded dynamically after the document is loaded.

So, when your JS runs for the first time after load `#checkAll` is not found. But, once the datatable loads the `#checkAll` is available.
To overcome this you could trigger click on document then apply your function to `#checkAll` by doing:

```
  $(document).on('click','#checkAll',function(){
    console.log('working...');
  });
```

**EDIT** Datatables has a [initiComplete property which can accept a call back function to let you know when the table has been completely loaded and drawn

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "initComplete": function() {
        alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
        $('#checkAll').click(function(){
            console.log('working...');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if DataTables has a trigger for when it's done messing with the DOM that I could use to attach the event?

Comment: Your first solution worked for me, but the second one (which I think is a better approach) didn't work because the FixedColumns doesn't start changing the table until after `initComplete`. I solved it by adding a timeout to the click trigger. Thanks for your help.